# check a table in database when a form is saved in php

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have a form which has a save button as shown below:

```
<form method="post" id="myform" style="text-align: left;">
<div style="text-align:center;">
    <button onclick="saveButton()" type="submit">Save</button>
</div> 
</form>
```

In that form, what I want to achieve is when a user press the save button then it should check a table in the database.

The table which I want to get it checked is `list_users`. `list_users` has 5 columns:

```
(1) user_name
(2) open 
(3) read_access
(4) write_access  
(5) LastActivity
```

When any user login `(let's user UserA)` then:

```
read_access => 1
write_access => 1
```

When another user `(let's say UserB)` login at the same time then

```
UserA
read_access => 1
write_access => 0

UserB
read_access => 1
write_access => 1
```

What I want to achieve is when `write_access => 0` then the user should not be allowed to save the form meaning on pressing save button
it should check `write_access` column in `list_users` table. If the value is 0 in `write_access` column, then the user should not be allowed to
save the form.

This is what I have tried:

```
function saveButton(e) {
    <?php
    $stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT write_access FROM list_users WHERE user_name=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_SESSION['user_name']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result2 = $stmt->get_result();
    $write_access = $result2->fetch_object();
    if($write_access->write_access != 1) { ?>
    alert('You cannot save the form');
    e.preventDefault();
    <?php } ?>
}
```

I am getting the alert message but the form is still getting saved. I am wondering what changes I should make in the code so that `with the alert message the form should also not get saved`.

Comment: Where is save (insert/update) query? Also, did you mean on alert, form shouldn't save in last line of your question?

Comment: Yes, on alert the form shouldn't save in the last line of my question.

Comment: Try `return false` after alert.

Comment: I tried `return false` after alert but the form is still getting saved.

Comment: Where is your save query?

Comment: There is no save query.

Comment: What you meant by "the form is still getting saved". Where are you saving this form data?

Comment: All the data inside the form is getting saved inside json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach to solve this is using `onsubmit` on the form instead of `onclick` on the submit button

```
<form method="post" id="myform" style="text-align: left;" onsubmit="return saveButton()">
```

And on the javascript function, use `return false`

```
function saveButton() { // remove e parameter
    <?php
    $stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT write_access FROM list_users WHERE user_name=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_SESSION['user_name']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result2 = $stmt->get_result();
    $write_access = $result2->fetch_object();
    if($write_access->write_access != 1) { ?>
    alert('You cannot save the form');
    return false; // instead of e.preventDefault()
    <?php } ?>
}
```

Here is the scenario :

Know that `onsubmit="return false"` will cancel the form submit,

then using `return saveButton()` and returning `false` on `saveButton` function will also cancel the form submit

Comment: @lllya there is little bit bug in this approach. What I want to achieve is on click of save button it should check `write_access` column in `list_users` table. If `write_access => 0` then it should not save the form.

Comment: @llya with your approach, I have to refresh the page to make it accurately work.

Comment: one more approach is using ajax for realtime checking the `write_access` permission

Comment: with current approach, you must refresh the page after `userB` logged in

Comment: because `alert('You cannot save the form');return false;` are printed before `userB` login